# Thumbnail carousel does not work on bootstrap-3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am following this answer to develop a thumbnail that is supposed to show a list of thumbnails and if user clicks on each it shows that image in the lightbox, however, the carousel does not work at all.

Does anyone have a better solution or probable know the issue?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/ptwqec4k/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
  </script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-inner .prev    { left: -25%; }
.carousel-control        { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As suggested in the fist answer, I created following file but this code has the same issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});


  </script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-inner .prev    { left: -25%; }
.carousel-control        { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output that I see is below, it does not move and arrows do not work!

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://bootply.com/quUFQAdYN2

Comment: @Skelly yes but does not work for me, place the code in a .html form to see. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Solution:**
To start off, I would just recommend you try to follow convention and having all your links for any styling in your header and all your scripts at the end of your document, after the body but before the closing html tag. This way your content is loaded faster before all the scripts are loaded and ran.

Also, the JQuery you have used for your page is v1.11.1 which is quite old. I would suggest always checking into the latest version of all you external resources and ensuring they are the latest version. JQuery's latest version is current v2.1.4 and I highly recommend you using it for any recent upcoming projects you are using. Note that the JQuery is loaded prior to the Boostrap JS because it is dependent on JQuery.

Lastly, I wrapped your Javascript/JQuery with a `$(document).ready(function() {` in order to ensure it runs once the document has been completely loaded and ready for any JQuery/Javascript functions you would want to call.

Below is the code I have used in an HTML file and ran locally and everything was working perfectly fine. The only changes I have made is moving the scripts below the body and updating your external resource to the latest JQuery. Also, formatted your code for better redability

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  

            <style>
                .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
                .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
                .carousel-inner .prev    { left: -25%; }
                .carousel-control        { width:  4%; }
                .carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
            </style> 
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 4000
        });

        $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
                next=next.next();
                if (!next.length) {
                    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }

                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Let me know if this works for you too.

**Edit:**  Added Screenshot of the page working locally with no console errors.
[image]

Comment: yes it works thanks, need to wait for 21 hours before passing bounty,

Comment: Not a problem glad to help. Just remember to follow that convention and to double check you have the latest version for your external resources :)

Comment: Are you testing in all browser. I also using this type of code but no luck on browser compatibility.

Comment: Well my solution does not particularly involve browser compatibility as it simply moves around existing code and just upgrades the JQuery resource. I tried on Chrome and Firefox (latest versions) and it works fine. It might be a case that the Javascript/Jquery is not supported by that browser, for example old IE browsers may not be compatible. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Just wanted to follow up, did you find any issues with cross-browser compatibility? If so, on which browser?

Answer (score 1):

I put your code in jsfiddle and it seems to work fine.
The problem might be at the external resources you used.

Here is the fiddle I made: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5dgw8jk/)

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks bur I know the code works I am wondering how to change the libraries to make it work. If you replace my code in a .html file you would see it does not work.